# How to use Enum types as function argument in anchor test

Tags: anchor, anchor-client

I was trying pass Enum type as argument in test function, but I am getting undefined error.

Here's the program enum and function:

```
#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum AppState {
    Finished,
    Active,
}


pub fn set_state(ctx: Context<Init>, state: AppState) -> Result<()> {
       // DO SOMETHING USEFULL
}
```

Here's test script:

```
import { App } from "../target/types/app";

type APP_STATE = anchor.IdlTypes<App>["AppState"];
await program.methods
       .setState(APP_STATE.Active)
       .accounts({
           user: user.publicKey,
           state: statePDA,
       })
       .signers([user])
       .rpc();
```

The error shows that APP_STATE is undefined.

Comment: Use ``{finished:{}}`` or ``{active:{}}``

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass it as `{ active: {} }`.

#### Enums with internal data

```
pub enum AppState {
    Paused { reason: String }
}
```

You can pass it as `{ paused: { reason: "Not enough players" } }`

Reference: [Anchor Javascript Types](https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/javascript-anchor-types)